# How to pass MVC View Session In Script

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a mvc controller,in Controller handles all Azure Api key in Session and pass it in view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Session["azureappkey"] = "xxx-xxxx-xxx-xx"; // pass to view
    return View();
}
```

In View:

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<p> @HttpContext.Current.Session["azureappkey"];</p> // got the session value working as expected
@{ 
    var x = HttpContext.Current.Session["azureappkey"];    // not working assign to variable and pass inside the script
    <script>
        alert(this.x);
        alert (x); // GETTING UNDEFINED
    </script>
}
```

Azure app key is written in Paragraph tag but is not defined in the script section.

Can anyone correct the implementation.

Comment: Whats the question? What's not working?

Comment: I  get the session value in paragraph tag or dom, when i assigned in variable x and pass inside the script block i am unable to get the values.How to store it in  variable and resuse inside others areas in view.

Comment: You're trying to mix C# and JavaScript. Generally, you don't want to do that.

Comment: when we use the model and assign to variable inside script how it working
<script>
    // Read embed application token from Model
    var accessToken = "@Model.EmbedToken.Token"

Comment: `<script>var x = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(HttpContext.Current.Session["azureappkey"];)); alert (x); </script>`

Comment: @MohamedSahir did you find answer? I tried below given solution but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The block you're currently using is a Razor block instead of JS block, and you're assigning session state content to C# variable instead of JS variable (see the scope below):

```
// Razor block
@{ 
    var x = HttpContext.Current.Session["azureappkey"]; // C# variable
    <script>
        alert(this.x); // JS variable with "undefined" state
        alert (x); // x is also undefined, because it not assigned yet
    </script>
}
```

The correct way to pass session state variable is using `@Html.Raw` inside `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
    var x = '@Html.Raw(HttpContext.Current.Session["azureappkey"])';

    alert(x);
</script>
```

If the Azure API key contains JSON string format, put `Json.Encode` inside `@Html.Raw` helper as Stephen said:

```
<script>
    var x = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(HttpContext.Current.Session["azureappkey"]));

    alert(x);
</script>
```

Working example: [DotNET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FEG3x9)